# ansible when statement iterating over list

Tags: ansible

trying to set a condition to restart an EC2 instance if reboot is requried after installing windows features.

```
  - name: Install IIS Web-Server
    win_feature:
      name: '{{ item }}'
      state: present
    loop: '{{ win_features }}'
    register: register_win_feature

   - debug:
      var: register_win_feature
```

the debug shows this:

```
      {
"register_win_feature": {
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "changed": false,
    "results": [
        {
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "feature_result": [],
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_item_label": "Web-Server",
            "success": true,
            "failed": false,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "changed": false,
            "reboot_required": false,
            "item": "Web-Server",
            "restart_needed": false,
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "exitcode": "NoChangeNeeded"
        },
        {
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "feature_result": [],
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_item_label": "Web-Asp-Net45",
            "success": true,
            "failed": false,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "changed": false,
            "reboot_required": false,
            "item": "Web-Asp-Net45",
            "restart_needed": false,
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "exitcode": "NoChangeNeeded"
        },
        {
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "feature_result": [],
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_item_label": "Web-Net-Ext45",
            "success": true,
            "failed": false,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "changed": false,
            "reboot_required": false,
            "item": "Web-Net-Ext45",
            "restart_needed": false,
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "exitcode": "NoChangeNeeded"
        },
        {
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "feature_result": [],
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_item_label": "Web-Windows-Auth",
            "success": true,
            "failed": false,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "changed": false,
            "reboot_required": false,
            "item": "Web-Windows-Auth",
            "restart_needed": false,
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
            "exitcode": "NoChangeNeeded"
        }
    ]
},
"changed": false,
"_ansible_verbose_always": true,
"_ansible_no_log": false
```

}

Then if i use this module:

```
    - name: reboot if installing Web-Server feature requires it
      win_reboot:
      when: register_win_feature.results.reboot_required == true
```

the module fails because the out put is a list

```
    "msg": "The conditional check 'register_win_feature.results.reboot_required == true' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (register_win_feature.results.reboot_required == true): 'list object' has no attribute 'reboot_required'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/var/lib/awx/projects/_5378__256_bowtie_test/roles/enx_bowtie_server/tasks/main.yml': line 35, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: reboot if installing Web-Server feature requires it\n  ^ here\n",
"_ansible_no_log": false
```

if i add a [*] to loop over all the results list, it doesn't recognize it. It also fails:

```
  - name: reboot if installing Web-Server feature requires it
    win_reboot:
    when: register_win_feature.results[*].reboot_required == true


    "msg": "The conditional check 'register_win_feature.results[*].reboot_required == true' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected '*'. String: {% if register_win_feature.results[*].reboot_required == true %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/var/lib/awx/projects/_5378__256_bowtie_test/roles/enx_bowtie_server/tasks/main.yml': line 35, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: reboot if installing Web-Server feature requires it\n  ^ here\n",
"_ansible_no_log": false
```

Can't get it working. i have searhed the web for a similar issue but with no succes.

:( any help would be much apprictaied.

Comment: did you try when: register_win_feature.results[0].reboot_required == true

Comment: results[0] will read the first item only and skip the rest. It is worth a try anyway. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) filter to get a list of all `reboot_required` booleans:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ register_win_feature | json_query('results[*].reboot_required') }}"
```

In your instance, the output is:

```
[False, False, False, False]
```

You can then use the [any](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#test-if-a-list-contains-a-value) test to execute a task if at least one of the booleans is true:

```
- debug:
    msg: "doing something"
  when: "{{ (register_win_feature | json_query('results[*].reboot_required'))  is any }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try as below

```
when: register_win_feature.results[0].reboot_required == true
```